# Regular expression to find all the image urls in a string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to construct a regular expression that finds all image urls from a string.
An image url can be either absolute path or relative.

All these should be valid matches:

```
 ../example/test.png
   
 https://www.test.com/abc.jpg
   
 images/test.webp
```

For example:
if we define

```
inputString="img src=https://www.test.com/abc.jpg background:../example/test.png <div> images/test.webp image.pnghello"
```

then we should find these 3 matches:

```
https://www.test.com/abc.jpg
../example/test.png
images/test.webp
```

This is the regex i am currently using (edited with the help of the answer here)

```
pat = re.compile(r'(?i)https?[^<>\s\'\"=]+(?:jpg|png|webp)\b|[^:<>\s\'\"=]+(?:jpg|png|webp)\b')
```

It works well but it finds also things that are not valid urls.
For example it currently finds the whole string

```
https://ads.world/profile/person/abc/url(/images/profile/people/488379.jpg
```

as a match instead of finding only the last part of the string
(/images/profile/people/488379.jpg) as a match

Look here at the example that i am testing
https://regex101.com/r/mcpmMM/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
(?i)https?[^<>\s\'\"=]+(?:jpg|png|webp)\b|[^:<>\s\'\"=]+(?:jpg|png|webp)\b
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/GksMAf/7)

---

```py
import re

s = '''img src=https://www.test.com/abc.jpg background:../example/test.png <div> images/test.webp image.pnghellobackground-image: url('../images/pics/mobile/img.JPG')'''
pat = re.compile(r'(?i)https?[^<>\s\'\"=]+(?:jpg|png|webp)\b|[^:<>\s\'\"=]+(?:jpg|png|webp)\b')

for m in pat.findall(s):
    print(m)
```

Prints:

```
https://www.test.com/abc.jpg
../example/test.png
images/test.webp
../images/pics/mobile/img.JPG
```

Comment: Thanks. i am now missing just this final part:
../images/pics/mobile/img.JPG

 (i added to the sample string)

img src=https://www.test.com/abc.jpg background:../example/test.png <div> images/test.webp image.pnghellobackground-image: url('../images/pics/mobile/img.JPG')

Comment: Thanks man! Can you also add a check for http and not just https ?

Comment: @AJ222 The `https?` will check for `http` and `https` (note the `?` at the end)

Comment: Andrej, the script also finds this whole string as a valid match. can you suggest a way to fix it?

https://schema.org","dateModified":"2022-12-29T09:34:23+0000","image":{"@type":"ImageObject","url":"https://i.dailymail.co.uk/1s/2022/12/29/09/66013321-0-image-a-7_1672304815075.jpg

Comment: Andrej, the script find this whole string as a valid match. can you check it?

https://pantheon.world/profile/person/Vujadin_Boškov/url(/images/profile/people/4224965.jpg

Comment: And this
https://www.health.harvard.edu/blog/\/\/domf5oio6qrcr.cloudfront.net\/medialibrary\/13342\/fef23683-0b70-49d7-8b32-d11ae842f633.jpg

Comment: @AJ222 I suggest to open a new question here on StackOverflow, where you put all test-cases and desired results. I'd try to look at it.

Comment: ,I edited the question here as i opened a new question and was told to edit this instead. let me know if you understand it now. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of that :

```
re.findall(r'(?=:[^\S])?(?:https?://)?[\./]*[\w/\.]+\.(?:jpg|png|gif|jpeg|webp)', inputString)
```

With:

```
"img src=http://another.org/hola.gif https://www.test.com/abc.jpg background:../example/test.png <div> images/test.webp image.pnghello"
```

Gives :

```
 ['http://another.org/hola.gif',
 'https://www.test.com/abc.jpg',
 '../example/test.png',
 'images/test.webp',
 'image.png']
```

This probably needs more test samples :)